# How to get data from server using Jquery in Asp.Net MVC 4 Application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying get data from database in my application,my js code looks like:

```
$(function () {
 $("#getNotices").button().click(function () {
     $.get("/Notice/GetItems", function (data, statusText) {
         console.log(data);
     });
 });
});
```

My controller:

```
[HttpGet]
 public IEnumerable<Notice> GetItems()
 {
    return db.GetItems();
 }
```

And Method GetItems:

```
public IEnumerable<Notice> GetItems()
{
    return _db.Notices;
}
```

It always returns:

[image]

Tell me please how i can get data, database keeps data i checked,from database?
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: maybe just silly idea but have you tried to call return _db.Notices.ToList(); in  GetItems()?

Comment: @JaroslavKadlec yes, I tried, it returns : "System.Collections.Generic.List'.

Comment: does it change behavior in case you'd change it in way it's described in my answer? e.g. change signature of method to return JsonResult? Then potentially try remove [HttpGet] attribute and try to acquire data via POST but that would more point to wrong configuration or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Json Action Results as follows:-

```
[HttpGet]
 public JsonResult GetItems()
 {
     return Json(db.GetItems().ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Comment: did that answer your question @Vladimir Khodakovskey ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try change code in your `GetItems()` method into:

```
public JsonResult GetItems()
{
    return Json(_db.Notices.ToList());
}
```

This way you're saying framework it should represent result as `JSON string`, in case you do not so then just `.ToString()` method is called on your result in background and then exactly this string is sent to your UI.